# Using an If in statement in a for loop

Tags: bash

I am having trouble using an if statement as the condition for running a script.

I have for loop that checks all of the files in a directory against a list of approved files with data attached.

```
for ( y in `ls directory` ) 
do
if [[ y =~ $(awk -F',' '{ print $1 }) ]]
then
ydata=grep $y file

sh $ydata
fi
done
```

The for loop is so that each file in the directory is run and it works fine

The if is to check if the file given is on the list. I need a condition that can fail as I expect only a small portion of y results to be approved and used in the script. [[This is not working for me]]

Finally I have a grep to pull the full line in the file (ex: filename,date,risk,level) the full line is needed as a parameter to run the script. But I do not want to run the script if the file is not on the list and I do not want to grep every single item in the directory if I can avoid it.

Any ideas?

Comment: Syntax of the loop is very much incorrect.  Also, why do you use `awk -F ','` ? Do the filenames contain comma ?

Comment: Do yourself a favor and use https://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: @LinuxSecurityFreak, even shellcheck doesn't help here (at least in the beginning), it just barfs on the for loop

Comment: @Gray_M, Bash gives an error on your very first line: `bash: syntax error near unexpected token '('`. It doesn't work fine. You may want to check the syntax of `for` with, say Bash's online help (`help for`), or [Greg's wiki](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/TestsAndConditionals), or well, probably thousands of questions here on the site. Also, you have quoting issues there, SE's syntax highlighting helpfully shows that. Please, fix those so that your script at least runs, and if you still have issues, come back with more details.

Answer (score 0):

@Gray_M I haven´t understood quite well what you need, probably you can give more details in your question or even post some sample of the data to be processed.

What I don´t understand is:

- **list of approved files with data attached** (files with attachments? Please explain)
- **each file in the directory is run** (this means files are scripts?) Or did you mean each file processed?
- **I expect only a small portion of y results to be approved and used in the script.** (used in what script?) A new script? the running script? the calling script? How is the calling script generated? Is the data a script? Can you post and example of the data?
- **$(awk -F',' '{ print $1 })** is totally wrong. Besides missing a quote, it receives no data, which means awk has nothing to process.

  I any case, to get started, below a simple script that might be of help:

```
 #!/bin/bash
scripts_folder="scripts_to_check_folder"
conditions_file="conditions_file"
for file in $(ls "$scripts_folder"); do
    if grep -F "$file" $conditions_file; then
        sh "$scripts_folder/$file"
    else
        echo "Will not execute this script: $file"
    fi
done
```

This loop will or will not execute some script based on the content of the **conditions_file** which basically includes script names.

Again, give us more details so we can help you more.

Answer (score -1):

Your question (if I read carefully) is about the if statement:
The condition is unlikely to give anything interesting: first of all: "y" should be "&y".

Comment: The _syntax_ of the `if` statement is correct (but it's not doing what is intended).  The syntax of the `for` loop is incorrect.  There are also other issues relating to quoting, command substitutions, and the fact that `ls` is used to loop over files. Please update your answer.

Comment: technically, the `[ .. ]` aren't part of the syntax of an `if` statement (even though `[` is often used in an `if`). If they want to use the `=~` regex match, they'll _need_ to use `[[ .. ]]` instead.

Comment: Looking at that for loop, it seems obvious OP's not using bash.

Comment: Arf... I should think 2x sometimes... Updated my stupid answer bracket's wise.